# Linking error while porting VS-2012 project in VS-2019

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2019, msdn

I am trying to build VS-2012(msvc-110) solution in VS-2019(msvc-142). It also used Boost library v1.51. I simply started by opening solution file in VS-2019 where it asked to change Windows SDK and Platform toolchain version (I choose WinSDK-10.177 and Platform ToolChain-142).

But I am facing linking error in a project which is as below

> Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc110-mt-1_51.lib'

I have searched all properties of project but couldn't found from where its trying to link  *'libboost_system-vc110-mt-1_51.lib'*

After setting the  flag ShowProgress to Show All Progress from Project's Linker configuration, the buildlog displays

> 1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:libboost_system-vc110-mt-1_51.lib

But I'm not sure from where its getting linked.

I also tried to add a dummy lib (xyz.lib) by adding it in linker's input list, which obviously gives the linker error

> Error  LNK1181 cannot open input file 'xyz.lib'

The error code for both linking error are different. So below are my questions

**1) What is difference between error code LNK1181 vs LNK1104 ?. (I didn't get it clear from MSDN)**

**2) Why its trying to link *libboost_system-vc110-mt-1_51.lib* and where I can find the setting to modify/update it.**

**3) Is it ok to go with older version of boost 1.51.0 and VS-2019? Will it impact any functionality?**

Comment: You won't be able to link your old boost libraries that have `vc110` in the name they were built with VS2012, as Visual Studio 2019 would be expecting `vc142`. You need to rebuild boost from source in VS2019 or download the prebuilt libs.

Comment: You can download pre-built libraries [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/) Support for VS 2019 (vc142) was added in Boost 1.71 So you'll need to upgrade to at least that.

Comment: @user20716902 I have already build the Boost 1.51.0 for vc142. The pre-build version for 1.51 are not build for vc142.

I am trying to figure out why its trying to link with 'libboost_system-vc110-mt-1_51.lib'. Where this link settings is provided i.e why its trying to link 'libboost_system-vc110-mt-1_51.lib'.

Comment: Ok here is how to change the linked lib, in Visual Studio go to the Solution Explorer, Right click your project and select `Properties`. You will then See `Configuration Properties`->`Linker`->`Input` Here you'll see the `Additional Dependencies` You should find the `'libboost_system-vc110-mt-1_51.lib` listed there.

Comment: No its not mentioned here, neither in `Configuration Properties->Linker->Command line -> Additional Options`

Comment: In your question you state that it processed `/DEFAULTLIB::libboost_system-vc110-mt-1_51.lib` which means that it must be present in your `Configuration Properties->Linker->Command line -> Additional Options` section. If you are not seeing it there it is likely that you are viewing the configuration for a different `Configuration` and `Platform` . For example if you are building `Debug` and `x64` Make sure that at the top of the `Configuration Properties` page that the Configuration and Platform are set to match.

Comment: By default boost tries to link some auto-selected version of libraries using `#pragma comment(lib)`. Define `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` to disable this behavior.

Comment: I checked for all settings as well pragma comment but couldn't find anything. 
However problem get solved after specifying vc110 version of boost libs in `Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Ignore Specific Default Libraries` and specifying vc142 version libs in  `Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`  
  
Thanks for everyone's help and support.